# Left Join misbehaving - VBA SQL

Tags: sql, vba

Table 1: Customer Info Data (has ~50K records)
Table 2: Sales by customer ID (has ~25K records)

When I am performing a left join of Sales data from Table 2 on Table 1 based on the Customer ID, the output has a handful of records (~500) with a unit increase in the sales quantity. For e.g. sales quantity for customer #1 is 200, the sale quantity that I am getting in my joined output is 201. Note again that this is only for handful of records, for the majority of the data, it is joined absolutely correctly.

The SQL query is a pretty standard one:

```sql
SELECT [Table1$].[ID], Name, Volume, Amount
FROM [Table1$] LEFT JOIN [Table2$] ON [Table1$].[ID] = [Table2$].[ID]
```

What is weird is that this error is only for a few records and it is changing only by a unit for all of them. What do you think could be the potential reason here? Note that I run this SQL query from VBA.

Edit:
Maybe if I add an image, it would help, I have masked my data:

Table1, blue colored column is the joined column, I have filtered for the ID where there is a problem:
[image]

Table2, source of the joined column, as you can see it is 20, but the value that has been joined with table 1 is 21. Interestingly, there is no ID with value 21 in table2
[image]

Comment: What do you get if you run the SQL manually?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @norie I did not try running SQL manually, but that will defeat my purpose even if running it through SQL directly helps me, because I am in the process of developing a tool that can do all the data processing that is required from excel directly as that gives me greater control.

Comment: Running it manually is part of the debugging process. If you get the same results as when running it from VBA it could mean there's a problem with the data, or database, if you don't then the problem is more likely to be with the code.

Comment: Are you querying Excel files using this code?

Comment: @jarlh Not sure about the dbms thing. I am using the following library: Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 16.1. Hope this helps, or let me know where should I look in to give what you need.

Comment: What database are you using Access? SQL Server?, MySQL?, perhaps even Excel itself?

Comment: @norie Well the debugging process is taken care of by SAS here actually. The data processing I am trying to do is currently done through SAS, and I am only working on migrating it to VBA+SQL.

Comment: @norie Yes, it is Excel.

Comment: SAS is debugging your VBA code?

Comment: @TimWilliams, Yes Tim. So, the process is like this - I receive a data quarterly in an Excel file (a huge one!) I do some calculations using VBA and then use SQL to perform join and grouping operations, and the output is again in Excel.

Comment: @norie - not directly, I debug my code by comparing the output at different stages. Not really a debugging, but yeah.

Comment: And, note that I tried to see what is going wrong for that subset of the data. So, I created two different datasets - one with the customer details and the other with sales data but with only one of those IDs where I am seeing the problem. I tried running the same query through this one-row-data, and I got a good result.

Comment: The other join syntax typically works fine for me, and it's good practice to be explicit which table your fields are coming from (I had to guess for the non-ID fileds so adjust as necessary) `SELECT T1.[ID], T1.[Name], T2.Volume, T2.Amount FROM [Table1$] T1,  [Table2$] T2 where  T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]`

Comment: Do you have a foreign key constraint in place? What is the data type of ID?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, I will try doing it this way. And, let you know how it works.

Comment: @Tarik Not sure what is a foreign key constraint. The ID is a string.

Comment: @TimWilliams It didn't work, still same errors.

Comment: Judging by the sizing markers, the CK column on the first screenshot is not a part of the query.

Comment: Seems like creating a simpler example with only the columns of interest would be a good place to start.  Even better if you could create a shareable redacted version.

Comment: I just realised that probably SQL is treating the numbers as a date for those particular records where the error is coming up.  Is there a unit difference between the starting date of Excel and SQL? Thanks all for your efforts till now! I can't share a redacted version, as I am unable to upload any files on the internet (restrictions!) The reason I believe so is that using Cstr function returns correct values.

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a space or something that makes seemingly identical IDs different. To make sure do a select distinct id on the sales table.

Comment: Umm...i checked for it, still the same. I also reviewed my ID field for any unintended spaces in both the tables, but it was clean. Plus, if there had been such an instance, the joined field should have been lesser in amount. In my case, the total of the joined field is coming out to be even greater than what is available in the second table.

Comment: Did you check on both tables? Select Id, count(Id) from table group by id